# Changing elements with JavaScript on elements that haven't rendered yet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, queryselector

I'm writing a chrome extension that edits the text contained within certain  elements on a page. One of the elements is in a popup div and so isn't rendered into the DOM (sorry if wrong terminology) until the popup is triggered. As a result querySelector() can't find the element to change it. Is there a way around this? I can only edit the chrome extension and not the source code of the page. Appreciate may not be possible.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but I'm using querySelector() from a chrome extension content.js. So I have no control over when it loads the DOM

Comment: Test the return value of `querySelector()`. If it returns `null` then just return since the popup hasn't been added yet.